# PHP readfile downloading current page code not url given to it

Tags: php, wordpress, download

Hi I've been working on this for a while and seem to be getting no where so I hope someone can help me out, i've read multiple different stack-overflow answers and tried multiple different things and don't seem to be getting anywhere.

**The Problem**

I am working on a Wordpress plugin which on a page in the public side of the website displays multiple buttons on one page all of which are meant to trigger downloads of different files. I have tried to debug this myself and have checked that the url is getting selected correctly and is then being broken down correctly providing all the correct paths and filenames and file formats for each file. Having echoed out a lot of the variables checking there contents are correct (Commenting out the headers).

**The following Italic text contains the original issue, However this is no longer the case, opening the pdf file in sublime text shows that the pdf is present. It seems to also contain a load of html before the pdf file (This is not present in my php but looks to be present by other php files and wordpress it's self) I have also edited the original code since thanks to @Marc B comment to add `exit();` in after the `readfile();` stopping any more html after the pdf data. All i need to know now is how can I delete all the code before the `readfile();` in php, which I believe will then leave the download with purely just the pdf and will hopefully open correctly.** *The following line doesn't seem to be getting the file it's meant to download. I have commented out and written the result of the parsed_url variable next to it incase i'm passing the wrong thing to readfile.*

```
    readfile($parsed_url['localpath']); /* /var/www/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pdfdownload.pdf */
```

Currently the code triggers a download to start and creates the attachment, it then downloads a file which although the name of which is the right name it contains the html of the current page instead of the data of the file it is downloading.

On the click of the button it adds the urlid into the url at the top and then on that being present the code then gets the id and finds the file url out of the url array to download.

Any help with this would be great heres my code.

**The PHP Code**

```
       if(isset($_GET['urlid'])){ 

      /*
      // Code is a modified version from
         author: pixeline
         website: http://www.pixeline.be
         last updated: 14 January 2009
      */


      $urlid = $_GET['urlid'];
      $filename = urldecode(urls_array[$urlid]); /* http://example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pdfdownload.pdf */


      // converting url to local path so Apache can find the file.
      // force download:
      // required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
      if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
          ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

      $parsed_url = parse_url($filename);
      $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
      $parsed_url['extension'] = $fileinfo['extension']; // .pdf
      $parsed_url['filename'] = $fileinfo['basename'];  // pdfdownload.pdf
      $parsed_url['localpath'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $parsed_url['path']; /* /var/www/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pdfdownload.pdf */


      // just in case there is a double slash created when joining document_root and path
      $parsed_url['localpath'] = preg_replace('/\/\//', '/', $parsed_url['localpath']);

      if (!is_readable($parsed_url['localpath'])) {
          die('File not found: ' . $parsed_url['localpath']);
      }
      $allowed_ext = array('pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'zip', 'doc', 'xls', 'gif', 'exe', 'ppt');
      if (!in_array($parsed_url['extension'], $allowed_ext)) {
          die('This file type is forbidden.');
      }

      switch ($parsed_url['extension']) {
          case "pdf": $ctype = "application/pdf";
              break;
          case "exe": $ctype = "application/octet-stream";
              break;
          case "zip": $ctype = "application/zip";
              break;
          case "doc": $ctype = "application/msword";
              break;
          case "xls": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
              break;
          case "ppt": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
              break;
          case "gif": $ctype = "image/gif";
              break;
          case "png": $ctype = "image/png";
              break;
          case "jpeg":
          case "jpg": $ctype = "image/jpg";
              break;
          default: $ctype = "application/force-download";
      }


      header("Pragma: public"); // required
      header("Expires: 0");
      header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
      header("Content-Type: $ctype");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $parsed_url['filename'] . "\";");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      header("Content-Length: " . filesize($parsed_url['localpath']));

      flush();

      readfile($parsed_url['localpath'] ); /* /var/www/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pdfdownload.pdf */
    exit();
    }
    ?>

    <a href="http://<?php print($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>&urlid=<?php print($downloadablepdf->urlidentity1) ?>">
    <button type="button" value="Download1" class="button button-blue"  >Download pdf one</button>
    </a>

    <a href="http://<?php print($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>&urlid=<?php print($downloadablepdf->urlidentity2) ?>">
    <button type="button" value="Download2" class="button button-blue"  >Download pdf two</button>
    </a>
    <a href="http://<?php print($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>&urlid=<?php print($downloadablepdf->urlidentity3) ?>">
    <button type="button" value="Download3" class="button button-blue"  >Download pdf three</button>
    </a>
```

Comment: You have to `exit()` AFTER the readfile call. Otherwise PHP will continue on wards and output all of that html you have after the download stuff.

Comment: Also, consider just using the `download` attribute on your `<a>` tag unless you *need* to do a bunch of extra checking (or have a larger than normal portion of your audience on IE)

Comment: Thanks @MarcB  i've popped `exit();`  in and now when I opened the downloaded pdf file in sublime text at the top of the page it shows a load of html and then shows what would seem to be the pdf file which is obviously unreadable but as a pdf should be fine. So basically all i need to figure out now is how can I delete anything displayed on the page before the readfile is called. Like a delete all code above as now it is printing nothing bellow it would then be left with the pdf. I think the above html is coming from other wordpress files.

Comment: @Jason I'm really trying my best to be cross browser compatible even as much as i hate IE i'm trying not to go with the html5 option

Comment: If the html has already been put out then you can not fix it from where this code resides. You need to intervene earlier in the wordpress proces. I am no expert on wordpress but there is probably some hook you can use

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't delete html that already exists in a php file. I created a separate php file to hold the php for downloading the files. Then back in the original file I changed the buttons to submit buttons and put them within a form with a post action to the new download.php file.

When a submit button is clicked it posts to the php file and triggers the download. This is the only way I could find to get rid of the html Wordpress was adding to the top of the page breaking the downloaded file.

Thanks everyone for you help this is now solved.